# Passing Image captured with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this code:

```
-(void)add
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]==NO)
    {

        NSLog(@"No Camera");


    }
    else
    {
        cameraUI=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.delegate=self;
        cameraUI.allowsEditing=YES;
        cameraUI.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.photo=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

}
```

---

Now i need pass photo in another view named `SaveViewController` without segue in this field:

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageField;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `UIImage *passImg` in header file. In ImagePickerDelegate method assign

```
self.passImg = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

And then when you pushing:

```
SaveViewController *savedVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SaveViewController"];
savedVC.imageField.image = passImg;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:savedVC animated:YES];
```

If you popViewController use **NSNotificationCenter**.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 SaveViewController *saveView = [[SaveViewController alloc]init];

 saveView.imageField.image = self.photo;

//push saveView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object of the desired view controller (SaveViewController in this case) and set the property. Then when you need to call that view, you will have to present that using the same object that you created. For example,

`self.photo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
SaveViewController *svc = [[SaveViewController alloc] init];
svc.imageField.image = self.photo;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];`